# ReactFire : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token | componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, babeljs, reactfire

I'm trying to start with React, following the example on firebaseBlog, I tried running the following piece of code, I get,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost/h/js/test.js: Unexpected token (1:28)
> 1 | componentWillMount: function() {
    |                             ^
  2 |           this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("items");
  3 |           this.firebaseRef.on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot) {
  4 |               this.items.push(dataSnapshot.val());
```

And the code being referred to is this.

```
componentWillMount: function() {
        this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("items");
        this.firebaseRef.on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot) {
                this.items.push(dataSnapshot.val());
                this.setState({items: this.items});
            }.bind(this)
        );
    }
```

Comment: `the example on firebaseBlog`, please be more specific, what example? This snippet is a piece of a valid react component, but you still need the rest of the component declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If your component declaration extends React.Component, like so ...

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

then your componentWillMount(), and other functions should be like this ...

```
componentWillMount() {
  ...
}
```